# Does Cesium Auride have any interesting electrical properties or is anything known about its electrical conductivity?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, conductors

I have read that this remarkable compound has relativistic electron orbitals. But is there any data about the energy bandgap structure? Or moreover, is it known if this material has conductive/semiconductive properties?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure quite how 'remarkable' the CsAu compound is - there are many alloys among the heavier elements. Whether the electrons are 'relativistic' or not has little to do with how their orbitals behave.

But, on the Au-Cs phase diagram (see A.D. Pelton in Binary Alloy Phase Diagrams, II edition, Ed. T.B. Massalski), both CsAu and CsAu$_{5}$ compounds exist. The CsAu phase is in the CsCl structure, with interpenetrating simple cubic sublattices. This phase is transparent and non-metallic. Even the liquid at this composition shows a dramatic reduction in conductivity (and a large decrease in volume) indicating a molten-salt like behavior.

Measurements by W.E Spicer [in Physical Review](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.115.57) indicate that CsAu is indeed a semiconductor with a bandgap of about [2.6eV](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.125.1297), and it is likely a direct gap. These experimental results were not far off of calculations by V.E. Wood and J.R. Reitz [in 1962](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022369762900069). It is considered a highly ionic compound as confirmed by [XPS measurements](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0038109879912201?via%3Dihub) by G.K. Wertheim et al.

Comment: https://www.uni-heidelberg.de/presse/news2015/pm20151029_einsteins-theory-of-relativity-explains-fundamental-properties-of-gold.html